# How to render view from other project in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, render, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am trying to develop project in which I have maintained its components as separate entity with no dependency on other projects. i.e. I will maintain cart as one module and if I need its functionality I simply call its actionresult which gives me the cart on my page that's all.

for developing that I follow the all steps mentioned  [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx) as it is.

I created my project structure as

[image]

I have to render view at **customer->viwes->customer->index.cshtml in 
demoplug->views->Home->index.cshtml**

for that I am calling the actionresult method as 
**@Html.action("index","customer")**

which return me **customer view**

but it gives me error that view is not found 
which **searches view demoplug -> view** folder but it is actually in **customer -> view folder**

please suggest to overcome that problem.

**In future I have to render the different views depending on the theme selected**

Comment: Post a screenshot or error stack please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you saved your Customer project in the Areas folder of the DemoPlug project, as the tutorial indicated? If yes, the you should modify your action method to include the area name.

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Customer", new { area = "Customer"})
```

To do the reverse and call an action in DemoPlug from the Customer Area, try this:

```
@Url.Action("MyAction", "DemoPlugController", new { area = "" })
```

Comment: hey Now I have to call action method of start project from areas action method

Comment: Hey--I'm not sure what you mean above. I'll need more details.

Comment: I have to call the action method of demoplug(main project) from customer(Area) action method.

Comment: Ok got it. See my answer above.